# C on smartcards

Tags: c, smartcard

I have the task to write some crypto stuff in C and make it lightweight. The idea behind making it lightweight is, that it could run on a smartcard which doesn't offer much computational power and memory. It won't come to actually running it on a smartcard and it won't be for any practical use.

However, I'm curious if I could run the program on a smartcard without major adjustments. I'm aware that I'd probably have to change something in the IO-part but let's keep that aside. And by "smartcard" I mean a regular smartcard which could be afforded by the majority of private individuals and not some fancy stuff.

To restrict the question a little more:
Could I run the program without modification if I only use 8-bit integers in my program and the architecture is >= 8-bit, aswell as stay below the memory limit?
If no, why not?

Comment: It can't be taken for granted that a smart card accepts C code. The only high level language with a significant probability of acceptance is Java  on a Javacard platform. The remainder depends on the OS and is likely to require a NDA.

Comment: I didn't take it for granted but I thought there have to be some that accept C code. But I didn't want to blow up my post size by extending it by such statements/assumptions. Thanks for the reply, though. What is "NDA" by the way? Non-disclosure-agreement? Are people not allowed to freely write programs for smartcards?

Comment: Yes, NDA  means non-disclosure agreement. No, so-called native cards are quite closed environments, since it is rather difficult, to firewall sensitive parts (either of  the OS itself or of other applications) against arbitrary user-supplied executable code - due to limited hardware support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to their limited CPU power, SCs mostly have their own security/encryption hardware and OS. The latter for instance controls access to critical features like the interface and key storage. Also, some of them have countermeasures against typical attack scenarios like differential cryptoanalysis, etc.

There are standards available, but which to pick depends on the actual card used. There are various SCs on the market with different capabilities and demands.

It is unlikely that your program will run without major modifications.

Note that the specs are mostly only available under NDA and possibly with additional guarantees from your side. The actual level depends on the capabilities and the card vendor.